# How to automatically start (or create and start) windows service after codedeploy to an EC2 instance

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2, service, aws-code-deploy

I am attempting to create a pipeline that can automatically deploy via AWS-CodeDeploy and start a windows service on an EC2 instance, but I am having trouble getting the powershell scripting correct.

I have the following:

Appspec.yml

```
version: 0.0
os: windows
files:
  - source: \
    destination: C:\temp\MyApp
hooks:
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: DeploymentScripts\applicationStop.bat
      timeout: 180
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: DeploymentScripts\applicationStart.bat
      timeout: 180
```

applicationStart.bat

```
c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe C:\temp\MyApp\DeploymentScripts\service_create_start.ps1 -ServiceName MyService -BinaryPath 'C:\temp\MyApp\MyService.exe' -DisplayName 'Test Application' -Description 'This is a test'
```

And the following powershell service_create_start.ps1:

```
Param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$ServiceName,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType 'leaf'})][string]$BinaryPath, [string]$Displayname, [string]$Description)

If (Get-Service $ServiceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {

    If ((Get-Service $ServiceName).Status -eq 'Running') {

        Stop-Service $ServiceName
        Write-Host "Stopping $ServiceName"

    } Else {

        Write-Host "$ServiceName found, but it is not running."

    }

} Else {

    Write-Host "$ServiceName not found. Creating new Windows service."

}

$ArgumentList = '-Name "{0}" -BinaryPathName "{1} -k netsvcs" -DisplayName "{2}" -StartupType Automatic -Description "{3}"' -f $ServiceName, $BinaryPath, $DisplayName, $Description

New-Service $ArgumentList

Start-Service $ServiceName
```

I created the bat file because it seemed that I could not launch a powershell script from code deploy with parameters. I am not otherwise tied to it.

My first problem is that it gets hung a prompt for "BinaryPathName" I have a feeling this is an issue with my quotes in one of these files.

My second problem (if I go enter this manually in testing) is that I get an Access is denied exception on the New-Service line.

To address this problem I have tried to use Start-Process an the RunAs verb to run an elevated powershell, however I am having trouble figuring out the syntax to add my parameters in (beyond the ps1 file name) with this syntax.

Am I even on the correct path here, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you can pass in parameters like this (as a single string), you better off using splatting:

```
$myInput = @{
    Name = $ServiceName
    BinaryPathName = '{0} -k netsvc' -f $BinaryPath
    StartupType = 'automatic' 
    DisplayName = $DisplayName
    Description = $Description
}
New-Service @myInput
```

reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6

Comment: This solved the problem completely. It seems that when the code deploy agent ran it, it was not getting the access denied message, so using splatting to get the parameters passed in correctly solved all of my problems. Thank you!